# Create term horizontal split that is 20% size key binding

Tags: key-bindings, window-splitting, term

I'd like a key binding that can create a term buffer in a 25 percent split. What I mean by that is, with a specific key binding like `SPC t c`, I'd like to open up a terminal in a split.

Comment: Are you looking for an existing key sequence that does that? Or are you asking for a command that does that (which you can bind to any key you like)? If the latter, please edit to remove references to keys and key bindings.

Comment: I want to create a new keybinding that does this.

Comment: I think your question should be asking for code that creates a command that does it. If you don't know how to bind a command to a key then that should be posed as a separate question (but it may already exist as a separate question - please search first). If I'm right then please edit your question to ask about a new command, not key binding.